# gulp.watch include from excluded directories

Tags: gulp

I have the following code where I want to exclude all files in the assets directory except the subdirectory named `content`. This isn't working because the `!` is taking precedence. Any suggestions?

```
gulp.watch([
    '**/*',
    '!assets/**/*',
    'assets/content/**/*'
]);
```

So if the directory contains:

```
index.html
assets/
    content/
        index.html
    stylesheets/
        default.css
```

I would want to watch:

```
index.html
assets/content/index.html
```

But not:

```
assets/stylesheets/default.css
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
return gulp.watch(
    [ '**/*' ],
    { ignored: [
        'assets/**/*',
        '!assets/content/**/*',
    ] }
)
```